# Why has the RAM a better compatibility when using DDR4_1, DDR4_2 on the Gigabyte B450 Aorus M?

Tags: memory

The [memory support list](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/B450-AORUS-M-rev-10#support-doc) of the Gigabyte B450 Aorus M states:

> Install the modules into DDR4_1, DDR4_2 for better compatibility.

Does anyone has an idea why this is the case?

Answer (score -1):

We can have a mobo with dual channel RAM configuration that has 4 dimm slots. As you mentioned, there are four memory slots on the Gigabyte B450 Aorus M, the two slots are DDR4_1 and the other two slots are DDR4_2. A memory module can be inserted into each of the DDR4_1 memory slot and the DDR4_2 memory slot to form a dual channel memory.

Dual channel memory architecture is a chipset/motherboard feature.Any two identical memory sticks will work in dual channel mode perfectly. And by identical I mean bearing the same clock timings, latency timings, need to be same type of course and same amount of memory. Can be from different manufacturers as long as the listed key elements are same.

Some manufacturer quoting dual channel on their modules does not means that that particular modules only support dual channel.. Just look out for memory sets in packs of two. They indicate two sticks tested and matched to work perfectly with each other.

Memory dual channel refers to a memory method that uses two compatible memory modules.
Single channel memory can only be read at the same time, or can only be written.
Dual-channel memory allows either of the two memories to be read and written simultaneously, and the memory bandwidth is doubled. System performance improves, but does not represent a doubling of system performance.

Generally speaking, dual channel means that two memory controllers control two memories separately, which is theoretically stronger than single channel performance, so it is widely used at present. The compatibility of the same type of memory module is better. The memory modules of the same capacity, the same brand, and the same specifications are perfectly compatible, but it is necessary to open the dual channel:

1. The memory size of each slot supported by the motherboard bios, that is, the maximum memory capacity supported by the computer hardware.
2. The memory capacity supported by the computer system.

Comment: There not only 2 slots. There are 4: DDR4_1, DDR4_2, DDR4_3, DDR4_4.

Comment: As I somehow can't edit my comment, here is the second part of it:
It also seems you aren't really answering the question, as I understand the ram support list from gigabyte, they are always assuming two identical memory sticks.

Furthermore some parts of your answer are definitely wrong, as you say that every two identical ram sticks, that don't have too much memory nor too much frequency for the mobo and the CPU will work perfectly.
But it is well known that the Ryzen processors have problems with some specific RAM models. (Most problems have been fixed meanwhile with a newer BIOS)